# Embedded matplotlib plot not affected by style sheet

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt6

I would like to create a simple PyQt6 GUI application with embedded matplotlib charts. I would like to use style sheets for my entire app, including to set the background color of the charts. However, the matplotlib charts are not responsive to changes in the style sheet (trying to set a black background still gives a white background chart).

Here is a minimum working example of what I have tried.

```py
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qtagg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Matplotlib Chart")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        # Create a Matplotlib figure and canvas
        self.figure, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)  # Wrap the figure in a canvas
        self.canvas.setObjectName("matplotlibChart")  # Set the object name
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        # Customize your chart using Matplotlib functions
        self.ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 5, 20, 15])

        # Apply a QSS stylesheet to the QApplication to style Matplotlib
        app.setStyleSheet("""
            /* Style the Matplotlib chart widget */
            #matplotlibChart {
                background-color: black; /* Set the background color to black */
            }
        """)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MyMainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I have also tried setting the style sheet as `QMainWindow` in the hopes the plot would inherit the parent's style, but that results in a black background with the chart background being white still.